# How to make the text in a Tk label selectable?

Tags: label, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm creating labels in Tcl Tk, but their text is not selectable (for copy-paste). How do I make is selectable?

I crate the labels using:

```
set n 0
foreach t $list_of_labels {
    incrr n
    set lbl2 [label .prop_menu.main_frame.val_$n    -text $t]
    grid $lbl2 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using read only entries, I replaced the creation of the label with:

```
set lbl2 [entry .prop_menu.main_frame.val_$n -relief flat]
$lbl2 insert 0 $t
$lbl2 configure -state readonly
```

And was able to create entries that act like labels but are selectable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't without taking a lot of the binding code from some other widget and applying it to your label. If you need this, you would be better taking an entry widget and making it look like a label. Something like:

```
entry .e1 -textvar t -relief flat -background [$parentWindow cget -background]
```

If you don't want the focus to move to these then add `-takefocus 0`.

Comment: I tried this, but I have a problem with putting a default value to the entry. The labels are created inside a loop where `n` and `t` get other values each time. I don't want to create a text variable for each new entry. Is there a way to put text into an entry without using a variable?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed: use something like `.e1 insert 0 $t`

Answer (score 1):

For the text in a label to be selectable *en masse*, there have to be bindings applied so that the program knows when to select it (as opposed to something else) and there has to be some code to place the code into the selection (or rather the clipboard). The latter is actually pretty simple to do with the `clipboard` command:

```
clipboard clear
clipboard append $text
```

The awkward bit is setting up the bindings and *showing* that the selection has happened. The simplest is just to do something lame like this (binding to a mouse click):

```
bind .lbl <1> {
    clipboard clear
    clipboard append [%W cget -text]
    bell
}
```

OK, that's definitely lame; you can do better! What you won't get is the style of highlighting that Windows's own built in labels often support (where you can drag out a selection and just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) as that requires the ability to draw the highlight, which Tk's label widgets simply don't have. (You can hack something with entries, but they can't do multiple lines of text, or you could use a text widget but then you have to do a *lot* of work with bindings to make it behave as you want.)